# How to Change Magento 2.2 Customer Password Hash During the Account Creation

Tags: magento2, customer, password, registration, magento-2.2.5

I want to change magento 2 default customer hash password to compatible with some other applications related to registering customers. currently i'm using magento 2.2.5 and I was unable to got solution of covert password_hash to plain text. Are there any possibilities to do this ?